# Execution plan flips Filter and Execute Scalar when using the PK, causes cast to fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, errors

I have some data tables that where imported in from a flat file source so everything is `varchar(max)` except `FileRecordID` which is a `int` that hold the row number the data came from in the flat file source (and is the primary key of the imported table.)

The following query works perfectly

```
SELECT *
  FROM [CLIENT]
  left outer join
  (
    select cast(ENTRY_CODE as int) as ENTRY_CODE, ENTRY_DESCRIPTION
    from [ENTRY]
    inner join [TABLE] on [ENTRY].ENTRY_TABLE = [Table].FileRecordID
    where ENTRY_RECD = 'A' and TABLE_RECD = 'A' and TABLE_CODE = 'CLTDISC' and ISNUMERIC(ENTRY_CODE) = 1
  ) as discounts on CLIENT_CLASS = ENTRY_CODE
  where Client_recd = 'A'
  --and client.[FileRecordID] = 10607
```

I get the exact number of rows I was expecting and everything is fine. However if I uncomment that last line so I only show the record from the `client` data table who has  `client.[FileRecordID] = 10607` it reports to me

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BK/TN' to data type int.

The problem is from `cast(ENTRY_CODE as int) as ENTRY_CODE` in the first outer join. `ENTRY` can contain text in the ENTRY_CODE column, however all records that have `ENTRY_TABLE` set to the line number from `TABLE` where `TABLE_CODE = 'CLTDISC'` will always be numbers only. I perform the cast as `ENTRY_CODE` may or may not have leading 0's and spaces so I am trying to get them to be well formed.

What appears to me to be happening is adding `client.[FileRecordID] = 10607` to the outer query causes the `where` clause not to be evaluated before the cast to int in the inner query.

I have tried things like adding `and ISNUMERIC(ENTRY_CODE) = 1` to both the inner and outer queries but it has no affect.

1. How do I fix this?
2. Can anyone explain what is happening so I can understand how to avoid this in the future?

Non filtered query planed execution
[image]

Filtered (non working) query planned execution
[image]
Notice the reversed order of the `Compute Scalar` and the `Filter`

---

Other things I have tried that do not work:

- Move `TABLE_CODE = 'CLTDISC'` in to the `on` clause in the inner join.
- Added `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` query hint to the query.

---

**Update:**
[I found a solution](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/trim-leading-zeros.aspx) but it is very "hackish" IMHO, I really would still like a explanation of how to avoid things like this in the future and how to do this correctly.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [CLIENT]
  left outer join
  (
    select ENTRY_CODE, ENTRY_DESCRIPTION
    from [ENTRY]
    inner join [TABLE] on [ENTRY].ENTRY_TABLE = [Table].FileRecordID
    where ENTRY_RECD = 'A' and TABLE_RECD = 'A' and TABLE_CODE = 'CLTDISC' and ISNUMERIC(ENTRY_CODE) = 1
  ) as discounts on CLIENT_CLASS = REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ENTRY_CODE, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
  where Client_recd = 'A'
  and client.[FileRecordID] = 10607
```

Comment: Another day, another victim of incorrect assumptions. http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/ and http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there are dba.se and StackOverflow duplicates, but it was far faster for me to post this link:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

In short, the Query Optimizer is really free to rewrite the plan as it sees best.  Sometimes, it means a column is transformed (CAST -> int) close to retrieval so that it doesn't have to be carried many steps forward before performing the CAST.

The only sure-fire way of preventing the error is to look at the CAST expression itself, e.g.:

```
cast(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ENTRY_CODE)=1 THEN ENTRY_CODE END as int)
```

Answer (score -1):

To test for values that can be converted to INT successfully, you need to test that all the characters are digits, or in other words, the string doesn't contain any non-digit characters.

```
WHERE EntryCode NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

The query optimizer should push the predicate down into the index scan on ENTRY, eliminating the rows before trying to convert them to INT.

Comment: `query optimizer should push` famous last words. Btw my "int test" would consist of `EntryCode > '' and EntryCode NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi  "famous last words"--good point.  Your answer is robust in all cases.  I will admit that I'm biased against ISNUMERIC() after reading an article on [SSC](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/IsNumeric/71512/). ISNUMERIC('7e5') -> 1 is correct but non-intuitive, so I avoid it.