# How do I CAST a date in a subquery? Currently getting an error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called `Source` in my table called `TPR`. The `Source` column is of datatype `varchar` and contains text like `January 2020` and `Q3 Completed`. When I run a query that only extracts the date-like fields to `CAST` as dates like so:

```
SELECT CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
FROM TPR
WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed`
```

I get the appropriate results. When I place the query above in a subquery to act as a filter like so:

```
SELECT CaseNumber
FROM TPR
WHERE Source =
     SELECT CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
     FROM TPR
     WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed`
```

I get the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

I've also tried the following but it too failed:

```
SELECT CaseNumber
FROM TPR
WHERE CAST(Source AS DATE) =
     SELECT CAST(Source AS DATE) AS Source
     FROM TPR
     WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed`
```

I don't understand why this is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE to get the wanted rows and then do the conversion

If the strings are not a correct format like seen below, you will get an error.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TPR(CaseNumber int,Source varchar(100))
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TPR VALUES (1,'Q3 Completed'),(2,'2021/01/01')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
>      SELECT Source
>      FROM TPR
>      WHERE Source NOT LIKE 'Q3 Completed' )
>      SELECT CaseNumber
> FROM TPR
> WHERE Source IN (SELECT Source FROM CTE)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | CaseNumber |
> | ---------: |
> |          2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15cf12e5db67f2aeeea7eb4dd060e110)*

Comment: Do you know why this is needed? Meaning, if I look at the order of execution https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution then the `WHERE` clause should execute first so why isn't the data being filtered in the subquery?

Comment: @AxSQLQuestions See e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29884/execution-plan-flips-filter-and-execute-scalar-when-using-the-pk-causes-cast-to. The optimizer can reorder things. Use `TRY_CAST`.